# Address out of bound and memory leak due to malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, strtok

I am trying to tokenize a string.

There are different lines that are stored in an input array (char**)

Am using the below function to store the different tokens that are generated into a different array .

```
int  tokenize_string(int max_lines,char *input_lines[max_lines],char **tokens)
{
    char *token;
    int index,token_index=0;

    for(index = 0; index < max_lines;++index)
    {
        token = strtok(input_lines[index]," ");

        while(token != NULL)
        {
            tokens[token_index] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
            tokens[token_index] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            token_index++;
        }
    }
    return token_index;
}
```

when using valgrind the below is shown

```
==25710== Invalid write of size 8
==25710==    at 0x400AA6: tokenize_string (functions.c:28)
==25710==    by 0x400953: main (main.c:29)
==25710==  Address 0x51c3048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==25710==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==25710==    by 0x40091B: main (main.c:25)
==25710==
==25710== Invalid write of size 8
==25710==    at 0x400ABA: tokenize_string (functions.c:29)
==25710==    by 0x400953: main (main.c:29)
==25710==  Address 0x51c3048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==25710==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==25710==    by 0x40091B: main (main.c:25)
```

I know that the problem is with `malloc` and the `for` loop.

//EDIT

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int max_lines = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *input_lines[max_lines];
    char **tokens;
    char *output_string;
    int token_index;
    tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*));

    get_input(max_lines,input_lines);
    token_index = tokenize_string(max_lines,input_lines,tokens);
    output_string= concat_string(tokens,output_string,token_index);
    print_string(output_string);
}

void get_input(int max_lines,char *input_lines[max_lines])
{
   int index;
   printf("Enter %d lines",max_lines);

   for(index = 0; index < max_lines;++index)
   {
       input_lines[index] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
       fgets(input_lines[index],50,stdin);
   }
}
```

any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: `tokens[token_index] = malloc(sizeof(char*));` is unnecessary (the value is being overwritten on the next line). Can you provide the code that calls this function? What are you passing in for `**tokens`?

Comment: What gets passed as `tokens`? How is it defined and initialised?

Comment: Also it would be interesting to know which code you have on `main.c:25` and `...:29`, as well which lines are `functions.c:28` and `..:29`. My crystal ball is broken,

Comment: am only passing the pointer as tokens.. `char **tokens; tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*))

Comment: tokens = malloc(sizeof(char*));//25  token_index = tokenize_string(max_lines,input_lines,tokens);//29

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a closer look at these two lines:

```
tokens[token_index] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
tokens[token_index] = token;
```

In the first you allocate space for a pointer and assign it to `tokens[token_index]`. The next line you ***reassign*** `tokens[token_index]` to point somewhere different, losing the pointer returned by `malloc`. It's no difference than having an `int` variable (lets name  it `i`), doing

```
i = 5;
i = 10;
```

And then wondering why `i` isn't `5`.

If the lifetime of `tokens` in the calling function is less than (or equal) to the lifetime of `input_lines` then you don't need to allocate memory here, the assignment from `token` (the second line) is enough.

---

There are other problems as well, like you not increasing `token_index` anywhere.

As for the "invalid write" it's really hard to say anything without a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows how this function is called.

Comment: i had incremented the value of token_index as i required that to know the total number of tokens

Answer (score 1):

In your `malloc()`, you're allocating space for the pointer itself, and then assigning the value to point to that. The next line, you overwrite it.

Assuming you need to use tokens as an array of the tokens after the lifetime of this function, what you're looking for is the following. You create the space for the string the token contains in the `tokens` array, and then copy it over.

```
int tokenize_string(int max_lines,char *input_lines[max_lines],char **tokens)
{
    char *token;
    int index,token_index=0;

    for(index = 0; index < max_lines;++index)
    {
        token = strtok(input_lines[index]," ");

        while(token != NULL)
        {
            size_t len = strlen(token) + 1;
            tokens[token_index] = malloc(len);
            strcpy(tokens[token_index], token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
        }
    }
    return token_index;
}
```

Also note that this function will just overwrite the same `token_index` unless you change it somewhere in the loop. You also have to be sure that `tokens[]` can fit all of the pointers to the strings that you need to create.

---

**Edit**

Okay, I'll start from the beginning and work my way down, but

```
tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

is not creating an array of pointers to strings, as I believe you're expecting. This just says `tokens` points to an area of memory with enough space for a single pointer to a `char`. You need either a predefined maximum number of strings that you're going to point to, or find a way to know that ahead of time.

In `get_input()`, you're doing a similar thing-- you use

```
input_lines[index] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

to try creating the space for a new string, but this just *points* to a pointer that points to a `char`. Given your `fgets()` call, and the limit to 50 characters, you can simply do

```
input_lines[index] = malloc(50);
```

So that you have the space for your 50 characters. After that, you need to ensure it is a null terminated string.

The most important thing to take away is that `malloc(sizeof(char *))` is **NOT** allocating the space for a string, only space for a pointer. These are not the same, and I would suggest reading up a little more about it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html).

Essentially, you seem to be writing outside of the range of the memory you're allocating.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so its redundant and can be removed If you want to stay on the save side replace it by `sizeof *tokens[token_index]`.

Comment: In this function i do not the number of strings that will be input so my address is going out of bound when using `strtok` .

Comment: A maximum number of lines are entered through command line and am taking those input lines of unknown length and then tokenizing them..

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your error is, could you edit your post and add a minimal amount of code from your `main()` so that we can see more of what's going on?

Comment: i have shared the same.. hope it helps

Comment: @Meghana the edit should help, but I have a feeling that won't help with the entirety of the problem.